# Trouble connecting to Amazon EC2 over SSH

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to my EC2 Instances on Amazon. When you connect an error - Permission denied (publickey). Installing cmhod 400 myPem.pem file does not help.
Connection log:

> OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011 debug1: Reading
>   configuration data /etc/ssh_config debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20:
>   Applying options for * debug1: Connecting to 54.214.31.168
>   [54.214.31.168] port 22. debug1: Connection established. debug1:
>   identity file wenglePemNew.pem type -1 debug1: identity file
>   wenglePemNew.pem-cert type -1 debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for
>   protocol 2.0 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2 debug1:
>   Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1
>   Debian-5ubuntu1 debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat
>   OpenSSH_5* debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT
>   received debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none debug1:
>   kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none debug1:
>   SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent debug1: expecting
>   SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY debug1: Server host key:
>   RSA (code) The authenticity of host '54.214.31.168 (54.214.31.168)'
>   can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is (code). Are you sure you
>   want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes Failed to add the host to
>   the list of known hosts (/Users/oktolab/.ssh/known_hosts). debug1:
>   ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>   debug1: Roaming not allowed by server debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST
>   sent debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received debug1: Authentications
>   that can continue: publickey debug1: Next authentication method:
>   publickey debug1: Trying private key: wenglePemNew.pem debug1: read
>   PEM private key done: type RSA debug1: Authentications that can
>   continue: publickey debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
>   Permission denied (publickey).

AMI creation and deployment of a new instance with a new pem file did not help.

What's need to do to connect to the server?

Answer (score 2):

> Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/Users/oktolab/.ssh/known_hosts)

What are the permission for `/Users/oktolab/.ssh/known_hosts` ?

Run below command to fix the permission:

```
chmod 0600 /Users/oktolab/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Also, could you provide the exact SSH command that you are running because:

> read PEM private key done: type RSA debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey debug1: No more authentication methods to try. Permission denied (publickey).

A lot of time above error appears if you use `ec2-user` instead of `ubuntu` as username and vice-versa. In your case, this seems to be ubuntu image so it should be `ubuntu`. These things will be clarified once you provide the exact ssh command you are running